# estimate the limit of $(\cos(4x))^\frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I was looking for a way to estimate the limit of $\left(\cos\left(4x\right)\right)^\frac{1}{x^2}$ as x goes to zero using lohospital laws, which I didn't consider to be possible given there is no 0/0 here...how can one do this using lhospital?

Comment: Take logarithms.

Comment: Use the logarithm and l'hospital.

Answer (score 4):

hint: consider $$\lim_{x \to 0}(\cos(4x))^{\frac{1}{x^2}}=\exp\left(\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos(4x))}{x^2}\right)$$

Comment: how do you go from left to right?

Comment: by the logarithm

Comment: @Bak1139 It is well-known.

Comment: im not familiar with that particular law of logarithm ...you  mind showing it?

Comment: It is a matter of continuity.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly,
$$(\cos(4x))^\frac{1}{x^2}=e^{\frac{\ln(\cos(4x))}{x^2}}.$$

Then,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos(4x))}{x^2}\underset{Hop.}{=}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-4\sin(4x)}{2\cos(4x)x}=\lim_{x\to 0}-2\cdot \underbrace{\frac{\sin(4x)}{4x}}_{\to 1}\cdot \frac{4}{\cos(4x)}=-8.$$

Moreover, $e^x$ is continuous on $x=-8$, therefore

$$\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\frac{\ln(\cos(4x))}{x^2}}=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos(4x))}{x^2}}=e^{-8}.$$

Comment: Beat me to it! +1. :)

Comment: could you explain just the first line of code...the exact actions you do?

Comment: I use $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$, then set $a=\cos(4x)$ and $b=\frac{1}{x^2}$ to get the result.

Answer (score -1):

It is well-known that, if $ \lim f(x) = \exp \left( \lim \ln f(x) \right) $, by continuity. Hence, $$\lim_{x \to 0}(\cos(4x))^{\frac{1}{x^2}}=\exp\left(\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos(4x))}{x^2}\right)$$Now, using l'Hopital's rule gives the inner limit to be $$ \begin {align*} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\frac{-4 \sin (4x)}{x\cos(4x)}}{2x} &= -2 \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\sin (4x)}{x \cos (4x)} \\&= -2 \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\tan(4x)}{x} \\&= -2 \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {4\sec^2(4x)}{1} \\&= -8 \cdot \sec^2 (0) = -8. \end {align*} $$Hence, the answer is $e^{-8}$. $\Box$

Comment: well-known is relative...;)